# May I change the word of "that " to "which"?

Tags: grammar

Sentence：All **that** he said is true.

Q：
May I change the word of "**that** " to "**which**" ?
And if can't, please say something about why can't.
Analysis as follows：
[image]

Comment: You can, but there is a strong preference for "that". Stick with "that" and you won't go far wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The relative pronoun **that** is used in preference to who and which after the words

> all,same,any,none,nothing,the only

Comment: very clear. Thank you for your help

Comment: To [**all who** apply](https://www.google.com/search?ei=_2WfXPjcH47jsAfIm4eIAQ&q=%22all+who+apply%22&oq=%22all+who+apply%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...37621.38852..39779...0.0..0.152.500.0j4......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i8i7i30j0i13.mabwFMTSpio)....[**none of whom**](https://www.google.com/search?ei=KGafXJWjB8_gkgX1_br4Dg&q=%22none+of+whom%22&oq=%22none+of+whom%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i10i30j0l5j0i30l4.32267.36824..37394...0.0..0.165.1538.0j13......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i7i30j0i67j0i10.fzqUDnI_bj4)...

Comment: the [**only which**](https://www.google.com/search?ei=TmafXNj6DMrjsAfUlr04&q=%22only+which+way%22&oq=%22only+which+way%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i30j0i5i30j0i8i30l2.32773.45243..45869...1.0..0.218.2227.0j14j2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i7i30j0i13j0i8i7i30j0i7i5i30j0i13i30j0i13i5i30.ZvRaMZ5MoY0) way is out

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer the OP's question. It's not the reason why the OP's relative clause begins with *that*

Comment: @Mari-LouA The reason is one of preference in constructions like the OP's, which is what the poster said. There is no other reason in this particular case.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: "the only which way is out" may be idiomatic, but it's not exactly grammatical.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible analyses.
A)
- All |that he said | is true. 
- All |he said| is true. The two mean the same thing.
- Everything (that) he said is true.

Those are relative clauses (above), so yes, you can use which. But I believe **which** sounds funny due to the second way of considering this:

B)
- All that| he said| is true. [referring to something someone said,not what he said]

- All this | he said| is true. [same as above]

As in:
He said all that is true.
He said all this is true.

**In that case**, **all this** and **all that** are an adjective plus a noun functioning as a direct object.
And **if that is what is meant**, *which* cannot be used because *all which* cannot replace *all that*.

It is not grammatical to say: He said all which is true.

I think that the difference between these two can be **lurking** and for me explains why I would never say:

"All which he said is true." even though it might be grammatical in the strictest sense of the word.